# New HTML elements not working with drag and drop function

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a intial div tag which accepts the drop functionality. Now within this tag i create new div tag which should also accept the same drop function. But it doesnot work. The newly created div tag should also be able to create new child div tags within it.

```
function allowDrop(ev) 
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) 
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) 
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"); // ID of the incoming dragged             element


  if(ev.target.childElementCount==0)
  {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    for(var i=0;i<func_list[parseInt(data)].length;i++)
    {
        var exp=document.createElement("div");
        exp.setAttribute("id", data.concat("exp"));
        exp.setAttribute("ondrop","drop(event)");
        exp.setAttribute("ondragover","allowDrop(event)");
        exp.setAttribute("class","Expression_Area");
        ev.target.appendChild(exp);
    }
  }

  else
  {
      var item = ev.target;
      while (item.firstChild) 
      {
        item.removeChild(item.firstChild);
      }
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    for(var i=0;i<func_list[parseInt(data)].length;i++)
    {
        var exp=document.createElement("div");
        exp.setAttribute("id", data.concat("exp"));
        exp.setAttribute("ondrop","drop(event)");
        exp.setAttribute("ondragover","allowDrop(event)");
        exp.setAttribute("class","Expression_Area");
        ev.target.appendChild(exp);
    }

  }



}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What errors are you getting?  Have you tried using breakpoints or console.log() to debug your code?  You should post all of your code to codepen.io and paste the link here so we can help further.

Comment: I am not any errors. Its just that the new div tags are not accepting the drop function.

Comment: You need to show the whole JS file, and HTML file.  We need more information.